# Did I connect the FT232 with the Digital isolator Data wired the other way?

Tags: usb, ftdi, digital-isolator, ft232

I think I connected the Data wires from the [FT232RL](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/163/DS_FT232R-11534.pdf) to the USB Isolator [ADUM3160BRWZ](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/ADuM3160-1503629.pdf) upside down.

[image]

I just want to confirm this, **Data -** of the one should be connected to **Data +** of the other ?

Datasheet page 7 of the isolator:

[image: Datasheet]

NOTE: The FT232RL is not the issue here. The wiring from the MCU to the FT232 works fine, I connected them to my computer and communicates. When I added the isolator between them and connected the computer, It could not detect any device on the usb port. I also tried to connect the usb data cables the other way in case I messed the USB cable, but this did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture is correct. M means minus (-) and P means plus (+) so this is not the issue.

Data+ must be connected to Data+, and
Data- must be connected to Data-.

It seems that the downstream and upstream ports are the wrong way though.

Comment: You mean that the microcontroller should be on the "right side" of the Isolator? (To the DD- and DD+ side?)

Comment: PC is upstream, FT232 is downstream